# Replace a word from a specific line in a text file

Tags: c#, text, replace

I'm working on a little test program to experiment with text files and storing some data in them, and I've stumbled accross a problem when trying to replace a value in a specific line.

This is how the formatting of my text file is done :

```
user1, 1500, 1
user2, 1700, 17
```

.. and so on.

This is the code I am using at the moment to read the file line by line :

```
string line;
Streamreader sr = new Streamreader(path);

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   string[] infos = line.Split(',');
   if (infos[0] == username) //the username is received as a parameter (not shown)
      //This is where I'd like to change the value
}
```

Basically, my objective is to update the number of points (the second value in the text line - infos[1]) only if the username matches. I tried using the following code (edited to match my informations)

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
text = text.Replace("some text", "new value");
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);</pre>
```

The problem with this is that it will replace every corresponding value in the text file, and not just the one of the correct line (specified by the matching username). I know how to change the value of infos[1] (ex: 1500 for  user1) but I don't know how to rewrite it to the file after that.

I've searched online and on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find anything for this specific problem where the value is only to be modified if it's on the proper line - not anywhere in the text.

I run out of ideas on how to do this, I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You could use `ReadAllLines` to get a list of strings, iterate through them as you are currently doing, and then write them back out (`string.Join` with `Environment.NewLine`, then just `WriteAllText`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var path = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
var originalLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

var updatedLines = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in originalLines)
{
    string[] infos = line.Split(',');
    if (infos[0] == "user2")
    {
        // update value
        infos[1] = (int.Parse(infos[1]) + 1).ToString();
    }

    updatedLines.Add(string.Join(",", infos));
}

File.WriteAllLines(path, updatedLines);
```

Comment: Thank you very much VinZ, this worked just fine for me. Many thanks @Selman22 too for his answer, this code here worked for me but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

use `ReadLines` and `LINQ`:

```
var line = File.ReadLines("path")
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(username));

if (line != null)
{
     var parts = line.Split(',');
     parts[1] = "1500"; // new number
     line = string.Join(",", parts);
     File.WriteAllLines("path", File.ReadLines("path")
         .Where(x => !x.StartsWith(username)).Concat(new[] {line});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I suppose that I have to replace "somevalue" with the string I'm looking to 'verify' (the username), but what about the {line}, is that where I write the string that I want to end up with? Do I have to write the complete string (ex: user1, 1550, 1) or only the value that I want updated (1550)?

Comment: you can write all line, or first you can parse it with split change the specific part and use Join to get full line.I will update my answer to show that.