# reading and replacing line in source file

Tags: c#, filestream

How do I read lines of text from the file and change them in the same place without using additional file. I want to edit the source file without creating an additional output file. Does anyone have any idea. I saw on the forum a lot of examples, but they use the source file without modifying it, creating a new target file.

Comment: What do you mean in source file ? If you want modify  an c# source code you can use roslyn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a word from a specific line in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926306/replace-a-word-from-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)