# How can I replace a line in a text file with a string variable?

Tags: c#

```
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(mainMenu.deckFile))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
```

I am already reading the line that I want to replace, but I don't know how I could replace the line with text stored in a variable. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you give an example of what you want to do? I don't understand the qs. Thks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a word from a specific line in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926306/replace-a-word-from-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "replace" a line in a text file.  You have to read the entire text file into a collection in your code, replace the line with your new value, then write the text file back out in its entirety.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

// find and replace the line you want.

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was stuck with "cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" after using this, but I realised I put the "File.WriteAllLines" command inside the "using(Streamreader) braces. :D

Comment: Yep, `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines` neatly encapsulates the `using` mechanism to keep you out of trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents of the file to a string variable or other suitable variable.

If you write the file contents to a string var, use mystringvar.indexof(myline) to see if the line exists then use mystringvar.replace(myline, mynewline) to replace the old line with a new one.
Then update the text file with mystringvar