# Edit specific word in specific line

Tags: c#, sat

I know this has been asked a few times, but I'm need a fast way to do this in files with different size (small and large files).

I need to edit scale factor in sat(txt) file. This is a first number in third line:

> 700 104 1 0 16 Autodesk AutoCAD 19 ASM 221.0.0.1871 NT 24 Tue
>
> Aug 16 09:02:14 2016
>
> **1000** 9.9999999999999995e-007 1e-010

Comment: Could you upload an entire file somewhere? To see an example of full content. On http://pastebin.com/ for example

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926306/replace-a-word-from-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file

Comment: @Darig29 http://pastebin.com/raw/Y3YZcaS2
It's a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest extracting a method and Linq:

```
private static String MyEditLine(string value) {
  var items = value.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);

  items[0] = "2000"; // let's change 1000 into 2000

  return string.Join(" ", items);
}

...

var target = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
  .Select((line, index) => index != 2
     ? line
     : MyEditLine(line))
  .ToList(); 

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", target);
```

Comment: But, this method reading the entire target file into memory and then writing it out again, yes?

Comment: If you have to write into the same file (i.e. update existing file), you have to materialize (`.ToList()` and read the entire file to memory); if you write to *different* file, you can drop `.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

assume you read your file and get a `String[]` called `file` and the number, you want to modify, is represented as `float`.

Than you can use the following code to first extract the line, you want. After this you get the number through `float.TryParse(..)`

```
int lineWithParam = 3;

String[] splittedLine = (file[lineWithParam-1]).Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);

if(splittedLine.Length == 2)
{
    float fact = 0.0f;

    String newFact = splittedLine[0];

    // or how ever you want to modify your factor
    if(float.TryParse(splittedLine[0], out fact))   
    {
        newFact = "" + (fact * 12.3f);

    }

    file[lineWithParam-1] = newFact + " " + splittedLine[1];
}
```

Here an executable example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NVgETo

after this you can write the `String[] file` back to the real file.

**Note:** this will not modify the `file`, if in the given line the first parameter isn't a valid `float`!